# Will Tails OS work on Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: operating-systems, pi-3

The [System Requirements page for Tails](https://tails.boum.org/doc/about/requirements/index.en.html) states that Tails requires:

> 2 GB of RAM to work smoothly. Tails is known to work with less memory but you might experience strange behaviours or crashes.

Seems like it might.

If it won't, is there a desktop-less Tails-like OS that might work better?

Comment: https://whitedome.com.au/re4son/pi-tail/ Pi-Tail
2nd December, 2017
Re4son’s Pi-Tail
Kali Linux OTG for non-rooted smartphones S-ticky Fingers Kali-Pi0 optimised for tethering
S-imple, one cable solution for bluetooth and wifi tether
T-wo cable solution for usb tether with smartphones
I-mage, configure, connect, boot up in two minutes from scratch
J-ust install ConnectBot and VNC viewer on your smartphone
A-utomatic switch between usb ethernet and mass storage

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it will not run on any version of the RPi. Looking at the link you provided, it specifically states that the OS requires an x86 processor, and that ARM is unsupported.

All versions of the RPi use some version of an ARM processor.

Comment: Ah, sorry then. New to RPi. Overlooked the ARM. Thanks!